# Не работает инициализация Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, fileupload, jquery-file-upload

Имею следующий код:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#photosUpload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    disableImageResize: false,
    imageMaxWidth: 800,
    imageMaxHeight: 800,
    imageCrop: true
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="fileupload" action="/ru/offer/addajax/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="photosUpload" accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" multiple>
</form>
```

Все нужные скрипты для базовой версии jQuery File Upload подключены:

```html
<script src="libraries/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="libraries/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
```

Однако инициализация не срабатывает. Перекопал уже всю [документацию](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki).
Задача моя в том, что при multiple выборе файлы должны сжаться в размере и всем пакетом прилететь на сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окей, нашел точную реализацию задачи на англ. версии stackoverflow.
Вот линк - [How to compress an image via Javascript in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser)